Select a value based on the highest priority
I have a requirement to get the value of a 'natural key' column (which is available in multiple tables) based on the below priority.
Table A - 1st priority (highest)
Table B - 2nd priority
Table C - 3rd priority
Table D - 4th priority
Table E - 5th priority (lowest)

If the value is present in Tables A,B,C,D, and E, then the query should pick the value from Table A.
If the value is present in Tables B,C,D, and E, then the query should pick the value from Table B.
If the value is present in Tables C,D, and E, then the query should pick the value from Table C.
If the value is present in Tables D, and E, then the query should pick the value from Table D.
If the value is present only in Table E, then the query should pick the value from Table E.
Notes

The records are grouped by 'ID'.

There is a possibility of the value not being in certain tables.

If the value is loaded from Table A and the value also exists in Table E, then the value loaded by Table A should not be overwritten by the value from Table E.

The tables contain millions of rowss.


Example
Table A



ID
Value




'1'
'Alpha'


'2'
'Beta'


'3'
'Delta'



Table B



ID
Value




'1'
'Apple'


'2'
'Banana'



Should Return



ID
Value




'1'
'Alpha'


'2'
'Beta'


'3'
'Delta'




Use UNION ALL to get the data from all the tables and assign each table an appropriate priority and then get the highest priority row for each id using the ROW_NUMBER analytic function:
SELECT id,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT a.id, a.value, 1 AS priority FROM a UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.value, 2 FROM b UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.value, 3 FROM c UNION ALL
    SELECT d.id, d.value, 4 FROM d UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id, e.value, 5 FROM e
  )
)
WHERE  rn = 1


Alternatively, use FULL OUTER JOIN and COALESCE:
SELECT COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id, e.id) AS id,
       COALESCE(a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value, e.value) AS value
FROM   a
       FULL OUTER JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
       FULL OUTER JOIN c ON c.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id)
       FULL OUTER JOIN d ON d.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id)
       FULL OUTER JOIN e ON e.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id)


Thank you @MT0, let me check and get back.

One option is to union tables from A to E in priority order (highest to lowest) and filter unioned tables to fetch just rows with ids not already contained in any higher priority table ...
--  S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl_a ( id VarChar2(6), val Varchar2(12) );
Insert Into tbl_a 
Select '1', 'ID_1_FROM_A' From Dual Union All
Select '2', 'ID_2_FROM_A' From Dual Union All
Select '3', 'ID_3_FROM_A' From Dual Union All
Select '9', 'ID_9_FROM_A' From Dual;

Create Table tbl_b ( id VarChar2(6), val Varchar2(12) );
Insert Into tbl_b 
Select '2', 'ID_2_FROM_B' From Dual Union All
Select '3', 'ID_3_FROM_B' From Dual Union All
Select '4', 'ID_4_FROM_B' From Dual Union All
Select '8', 'ID_8_FROM_B' From Dual;

Create Table tbl_c ( id VarChar2(6), val Varchar2(12) );
Insert Into tbl_c 
Select '3', 'ID_3_FROM_C' From Dual Union All
Select '4', 'ID_4_FROM_C' From Dual Union All
Select '5', 'ID_5_FROM_C' From Dual Union All
Select '6', 'ID_6_FROM_C' From Dual;

--  S Q L :
  Select   id, val 
  From     tbl_a 
Union All
  Select   id, val 
  From     tbl_b
  Where    id Not In( Select id From tbl_a ) 
Union All
  Select   id, val 
  From     tbl_c
  Where    id Not In( Select id From tbl_a ) And
           id Not In( Select id From tbl_b )
Order By   id

/*  R e s u l t : 
ID  VAL
--  --------------
1   ID_1_FROM_A
2   ID_2_FROM_A
3   ID_3_FROM_A
4   ID_4_FROM_B
5   ID_5_FROM_C
6   ID_6_FROM_C
8   ID_8_FROM_B
9   ID_9_FROM_A      */

See the fiddle here.
